# Why does == not work while comparing two object type variables boxed with same int value

Tags: c#, equality, singly-linked-list, equals-operator

While trying to implement a simple singly linked list in C#, I noticed that `==` does not work while comparing two object type variables boxed with an int value but `.Equals` works.

Wanted to check why that is so.

The below snippet is a generic object type Data property

```
public class Node {
    /// <summary>
    /// Data contained in the node
    /// </summary>
    private object Data { get; set; };
}
```

The below code traverses the singly linked list and searches for a value of type object -

```
/// <summary>
/// <param name="d">Data to be searched in all the nodes of a singly linked list
/// Traverses through each node of a singly linked list and searches for an element
/// <returns>Node if the searched element exists else null </returns>
public Node Search(object d)
{
    Node temp = head;

    while (temp != null)
    {
        if (temp.Data.Equals(d))
        {
            return temp;
        }

        temp = temp.Next;
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, if I replace

```
temp.Data.Equals(d)
```

with 
    temp.Data == d

it stops working even though `temp.Data` and `d` both have the value '3'. Any reasons why `==` does not work on object type variables?

Here's the snippet from the Main function -

```
SinglyLinkedList list = new SinglyLinkedList();
list.Insert(1);
list.Insert(2);
list.Insert(3);
list.Insert(4);
list.Insert(5);

list.Print();

Node mid = list.Search(3);
```

I believe since I am passing an int value `3` and the Search method expects an object type, it would have successfully boxed 3 as a object type. However, not sure why `==` doesn't work but `.Equals` does.

Is `==` operator overloaded for value types only?

Comment: You should use generics.

Comment: Yes, this was just for practice purposes. I realize Generics would already have a LinkedList implementation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two reasons:

- `Equals` is not bounded with `==` and vice versa, and by default checks for reference-equality:

  As you can read in the specifications of [`.Equals` vs `==`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

  > By default, the operator `==` tests for reference equality by determining if two references indicate the same object, so reference types do not need to implement operator `==` in order to gain this functionality. When a type is immutable, meaning the data contained in the instance cannot be changed, overloading operator `==` to compare value equality instead of reference equality can be useful because, as immutable objects, they can be considered the same as long as they have the same value. Overriding operator `==` in non-immutable types is not recommended.
  >
  > Overloaded operator `==` implementations should not throw exceptions. Any type that overloads operator `==` should also overload operator `!=`.

  Although the compiler will throw an error if you do not override the `!=` as well, and will warn that you better override both `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode`.

  So overriding/overloading the `.Equals`, `==` and `!=` are different things. Overriding `.Equals` has no effect on overloading `==` and `!=`. After all the `==` is a custom operator. Although it is not wise to do so, you could use it for another purpose than an equality check.
- Furthermore operators are resolved at **compile-time**:

  Take the following example the following `csharp` interactive shell program:

  ```
  $ csharp
  Mono C# Shell, type "help;" for help

  Enter statements below.
  csharp> public class Foo {
        >  
        > public int data;
        >  
        > public static bool operator == (Foo f1, Foo f2) {
        >     return f1.data == f2.data;
        > }
        >  
        > public static bool operator != (Foo f1, Foo f2) {
        >  
        >     return f1.data != f2.data;
        > }
        >  
        > }
  (1,15): warning CS0660: `Foo' defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.Equals(object o)
  (1,15): warning CS0661: `Foo' defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.GetHashCode()
  csharp> object f = new Foo();
  csharp> object f2 = new Foo();
  csharp> f == f2
  false
  csharp> Foo f3 = f as Foo;
  csharp> Foo f4 = f2 as Foo;
  csharp> f3 == f4
  true
  ```

  As you can see, `==` gives a different result if you call the objects as `object`, or as `Foo`. Since you use an `object`, the only binding at compile time C# can make is the one with reference equality.

Comment: Pretty cool explanation. Thanks for citing the example on how I could override == and != for tweaking the reference equality to comparing values.

Comment: @Ankit no, you cannot override operators.  You can only overload them.  Note that `int` does, of course, overload `==`.  The key here is the static (compile-time) type, which is important because this is an overload rather than an override.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @phoog. Reading your comment and then this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/07/07/c.net-little-pitfalls-operators-are-overloaded-not-overridden.aspx) made me understand that operators are indeed overloaded and bound at compile time and not overridden as they are static. The link does point out  a workaround of operator overriding - using a virtual method inside the overloaded operator and then the virtual method can be overridden :)

Comment: @Ankit but that technique is only of limited use.  In particular, if the System.Object overload of == is called, it won't matter whether you've used a virtual method or reflection or a magic pink pony in your own class's overload of that operator, because that overload will never get called.

Comment: Right @phoog. I don't like the == operator's functionality being so constrained for System.Object that on one hand their overload is statically bound at compile time and on the other, it is impossible to override it. Haven't read much about the `dynamic` keyword introduced in C# 4.0. I doubt if it allows dynamic binding of System.Object overload of == though to a custom value equality check instead of reference equality. WIll try to read more on it.

Answer (score 6):

It's because the `System.Object` implementation of `==` tests reference equality, like the static `Equals(object, object)`, while instance `Equals(object)` is overloaded, so it checks the actual value.

When you box a value type twice, you get two different instances, so of course reference equality fails.

The operator, being static, is bound at compile time, so there is no dynamic dispatch.  Even with strings, which are already reference types and are therefore not boxed when assigned to an object-type variable, you can get an unintended reference comparison with the == operator if one of the operands has a static type other than `string`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the reference equality check that `==` did was unintended. I'll keep this in mind for strings as well in future.

Answer (score 4):

The operator `==` is like an overloaded static function selected based on the compile time types. In your case the type of the values is `Object`, for which the `==` operator implements reference equality.

On the other hand `.Equals` is virtual and overridden, so it will do the comparison based on the actual types.

Comment: Right. Thanks @hege_hegedus with the question edits and letting me know of `==` implementing reference equality vs `.Equals` which is virtual and overriden and hence compares actual types.